# Why font does not fit in container with ellepsis

Tags: html, css

I have this div containing a text set to show "..." `ellipsis` when too long. For that I need to put the `overflow` at `hidden` and set a `max-width`. For the `width` attribute and `ellipsis` to work the container also needs to be in a `block` mode (or inline-block). Also the `white-space: nowrap` is needed. I realized that the container is not taking what it should as its height for the font to fully fit in itself.

see: http://codepen.io/Reblutus/pen/ebcgs

I realized that I had to boost the `line-height` to `1.5em` (sometimes `1.3em` is enough in some browsers) for it to fit.

I have trouble understanding why a font would not use enough height to fit itself with a line-height of the same size as its font-size.

Does anyone have some useful info on this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `line-height` is saying to only take into consideration `1em` of height - that's only enough to get to the baseline, and any letters that drop below it (such as `pqgjy` and so on) won't have the space they need.

A typical default for `line-height` is between `1.15` and `1.2`. This will allow enough space for the letters.

Comment: The thing is depending on the font (I am using a custom font) I may need up to 1.5em on some system (TVs). This breaks my layout and I need to position:relative and set top:-Xpx. On the standard, I think a font should use all the space it needs to be shown completely.  without having to "hack" the line-height. It looks to me more like a glitch in the spec...

Comment: I will also add that this answer will not be accepted as the answer since the solution given here is already given in my question. Also this answer imply that the default line-height of 1em reserve only enough space to get to the baseline which is wrong. If that was the case, you would see no stems or tail from those letters, for example  q would look like an a and y would look like a v.